# Unable to get reply from bot created with BotFramework hosted in Azure with database connection

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, bots, botframework

The bot that has been developed runs in the emulator locally without any problem.

But when we hosted it in Azure. We're not getting any reply from bot.

I tried testing the Bot Connection in dev.botframework.com, I get an "Endpoint authorization succeeded message".

can anyone let me know what could be the issue.?

Comment: What's the channel that you're using? Telegram, fb, skype?

Comment: Skype and Webchat

Comment: There is a good chance that I did something wrong with the connection string.

 <add name="DBCS" connectionString="Data Source=xxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=<dbname>;Integrated Security=False;
 TrustServerCertificate=False;User ID=yyy@xxx;Password=####;Connection Timeout=30" />

Comment: Did you include System.Data.SqlClient as a provider?

Comment: I tried including that also. It didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is fixed now.

I removed the database connection string from web.config file and configured it in Azure Web App service -> Application settings.

I gave the connection string name I gave in MessageController.cs while creating it through ConfigurationManager.connectionString

```
 ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString
```

Also, I updated the BotBuilder from v3.0.0 to v3.0.1 as it had a bug fix with Bot.Connector which I had used in my code.

Both these changes helped.

Answer (score 0):

Arjun

As you mentioned in the question, it works well in `localhost`. But when you host inside `Azure app services` it doesn't work. If end points are working properly you will normally get default message from the `Bot` whether you're connection to a DB or not. Please check your endpoint,

When you connect to the azure your endpoint will look like,
`http://azuregetstartessamplebot.azurewebsites.net`

But keep in mind when you adding that URL as your endpoint, include `https` instead `http` and add `/API/Messages` in the end of your URL. Then final endpoint URL looks like,

`https://azuregetstartessamplebot.azurewebsites.net/API/Messages`

hope this answer will help you. Try it. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your reply..

My endpoint is already like what you have mentioned.

From dev.bot framework I get a success message

"Endpoint Authorization Succeeded."

But, Whenever I send a message. It gets added as internal server error in issues of the channel.

Comment: Are you able to debug your bot online to catch exceptions?  It's possible Bot Framework is sending you an ActivityType other than "message" and your bot isn't handling it. For example, you may be getting "conversationUpdated" Activity with a null message body.

Comment: The issue is fixed now. The bot.connector I used had a bug and it was fixed in 3.0.1. So I updated them.